# Probability density functions. Expected values

Tags: probability

Need help with answering questions in this style. I think I'm supposed to integrate $f(x)$ over the range $0.9-0$. Not sure what else to do after that. [image]

Comment: Hint: profit is a function of life length and is therefore a r.v. Calculate the expected value w.r.t. this new r.v.

Answer (score 1):

By integration, as you suggest, you can find $P(X \le .9) \approx .59.$ (I suppose you should find this value correct to four places.)

So the manufacturer loses 2 pounds with probability $.59$ and gains 4 pounds with probability $(1 - .59).$